# Problems with Kafka configuration using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Our team has been experimenting problems with Kafka. This problems has been there since we started developing our application.

At the beginning these problems were solved quickly. "It is failing? Just restart the server". Since we want to start distributing our app with the public, this "solution" is not viable anymore.

The problems we are facing are basically two:

#### Consumers stop working

This is a recurrent one. All of a sudden some consumers just stop. The message is sent to Kafka successfully, we can even see the actual message using Kafka Tool, but the consumer just doesn't work.

#### Cycled messages

This is the opposite. Sometimes a message is sent and the consumer just keep consuming the message until we restart the server.

We tried configuring Kafka directly into the server, but we realize that for some reason Kafka ignores these configurations and takes the configuration directly from Spring Boot.

Our configuration looks like this:

Consumer:

```
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 5000000);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 10800000);
```

Producer:

```
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.KAFKA_HOST);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 5000000);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 10800000);
```

You can see the extreme timeout and size values, this because we thought the problems were related to the size of the message or the timeout of the server. We even redesigned all our app flux so we can send smaller messages, that's when we realize that's not the root problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Kafka Version 0.10

Spring Boot Version 1.5.7 Dalston.SR4

We are using the spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka dependency.

We checked the logs but there are no recognizable errors. In fact, there are only info messages but none of them says something useful.

Comment: What version of Boot and spring-kafka? The current versions are 2.0.4 and 2.1.7 respectively. What version of kafka broker? You need to show more configuration - i.e. are you using Boot's auto-configured factories or your own, etc, etc. Have you taken a thread dump to see what the container thread(s) are doing? Is there anything in the log that indicates some problem?

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Boot 1.5 pulls in a very old version of spring-kafka (1.1.x) which is no longer supported. Boot has strict rules about dependency versioning. As noted on [the Spring for Apache Kafka project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka):

> All users with brokers >= 0.10.x.x are recommended to use spring-kafka version 1.3.x or higher due to its simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62.

The current 1.3.x version is [1.3.5](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn). Try upgrading to that version and the 0.11 kafka-clients jar.

With 1.1.x, there is complex logic with slow listeners required to pause/resume the consumer to avoid the broker rebalancing. While I haven't seen it myself, I have seen reports that consumers don't properly resume after a pause.

Thanks to KIP-62, this logic is no longer required because heartbeats are sent in the background. You do, however, need to ensure that the `max.poll.interval.ms` is large enough to support processing `max.poll.records`.

If you can, it would be even better if you upgrade to boot 2.0.4 which pulls in the latest spring-kafka 2.1.7.